Singularities of $\frac{1}{1-z^n}$
I'm looking to classify the singularities of $g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^n}$ and compute the residue at each pole.
Now, $g(z)$ has singularities at the roots of unity $w^k$, where $w=\exp\{\frac{2\pi \textbf i}{n}\}$.
I know the singularities are simple poles, but I can't rigorously prove why. I also have difficulty computing the residues at each pole.
I know if $f(z) = \frac{a(z)}{b(z)}$  is the ratio of two holomorphic functions and $a$ has a simple zero at $z_0$ and $b$ is non-vanishing there, then $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ and the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is $\frac{a(z_0)}{b'(z_0)}$.  Applied to this, the residue of $g$ at $w^k$ is $-\frac{1}{nw^{k-1}}$, but it's supposedly $-\frac{w^k}{n}$.
Any help with this would be great. Thank you!

The limit of $(w^k-z)g(z)=\frac{w^k-z}{1-z^n}$ as $z\to w^k$ is the same as the reciprocal of the limit that you would use to compute derivative of $g(z)$ at $z=w^k$. That, in turn, you know is $nz^{n-1}$ evaluated at $z=w^k$ is different from zero. Therefore $(z-w^k)g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=w^k$.
